# PrimeNG calendar won't show popup

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to open the calendar with PrimeNG label but everytime I click on the label won't open the calendar, here my code:
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StoreMenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ButtonModule,
    InputTextModule,
    FormsModule,
    InputNumberModule,
    CalendarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
      myDate1!: Date;
myEvent(evt: any) 
{
console.warn(evt)
}
}
```

component.html

```
 </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label for="icon">Icon</label>
                        <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="myDate1" [showIcon]="true" inputId="icon"></p-calendar>
                    </div>
```

every other primeNG component working I have a problem with just this, thanks who gonna answer me

Comment: Putting `for="someId"` on a label only applies with inputs like checkbox or radio, in the docs for that component though there is a `toggle` method you could fire to it if you had like `(click)="someMethod()"` that then from the ts had a reference to that component you could do like `this.calendar.toggle()` but at the moment there's nothing interacting with your calendar that would be expected to toggle its visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the ended I resolved by adding:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

in the module